# promt/alert a user on delete button & run the script to delete

Tags: php, javascript

I want to prompt a user if he wants to do the operation (delete) - say "yes" or "no" with an alert box and if yes then run the delete script or if no then do nothing

I dont know javascript much hence if anyone could get the right script for php with javascript

I want a delete link/button to show an alert while clicking and asked the user to proceed or not, and run the script according to that

Comment: No one wants to write your app for you. At least try first, and report back with the results.

Comment: please dont take it that way, I want only a solutions/script like sample which do so, and I could make it from understanding that.I know its a small thing used always by everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im not sure you can change the button text but the basic window is:

```
document.getElementById('myDeleteButton').onclick = function(){ 
  return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?'); 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link that the browser will only go to if the user confirms:

```
<a onclick="javascript:return confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete? This action cannot be undone.')" href="DELETE-SCRIPT-URL">Delete</a>
```

Of course, this will only work if the person has JavaScript enabled, if they don't then it will just be a normal link. The far more complex alternative that would work for people without JavaScript would be to have the link lead the person to a confirmation page, which will then bring them to the actual delete page. I wouldn't advise that, though, since its fairly bad design and requires the user to go through an extra page.

Comment: inline handler definitions smell bad :-)